# ListView does not always refresh the databound rows from WCF service call, UWP C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, uwp

VisualStudio 2015, UWP, C#

I'm trying to refresh the data after submitting the checked items and updating database through WCF service. The checked items should always be removed after refresh. Sometimes (1 out of 5 times) it doesn't remove all the check items on refresh. But if I click the refresh button a second or two afterwards then the new data populates the listview correctly. Any ideas why this is not always working? I'm new to UWP so I'm just kinda winging it for now.

```
[Undo][Refresh][Submit]
-----------------------
      Item 1
-----------------------
      Item 2
-----------------------
      Item 3
-----------------------
√     Item 4
-----------------------
√     Item 5
-----------------------
```

Submit button check icon in menu

```
    private void SubmitDropOffButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool needsRefresh = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < ShipListView.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var container = ((ListViewItem)(ShipListView.ContainerFromItem(ShipListView.Items[i])));
            var chk = Child<CheckBox>(container, "ItemCheckBox");

            if (chk != null)
            {
                if (chk.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    ServiceLocal.ShipGroup ShipGroup = (ServiceLocal.ShipGroup)container.Content;
                    WriteSubmitDropOff(ShipGroup.id);
                    needsRefresh = true;
                }
            }

        }

        if (needsRefresh == true)
        {
             RefreshDropOffButton_Click(null, null);
        }

    }
```

Submit checked items

```
    private async void WriteSubmitDropOff(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceLocal.Service1Client client = new ServiceLocal.Service1Client();
            await client.SubmitDropOffAsync(id);
            await client.CloseAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Refresh Listview

```
    private async void RefreshDropOffButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceLocal.Service1Client client = new ServiceLocal.Service1Client();
        var itemSource = await client.GetShipData2Async(1);
        ShipListView.ItemsSource = null;
        ShipListView.ItemsSource = itemSource;
        await client.CloseAsync();
    }
```

Comment: You probably need to await WriteSubmitDropOff with a Task<bool> maybe. It looks like your processing is still being done while the refreshing is completed.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith That sounds like a realistic suggestion, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these in your code.

```
bool result = await WriteSubmitDropOff(ShipGroup.id);
private async Task<bool> WriteSubmitDropOff(int id)
{
    try
    {
        ServiceLocal.Service1Client client = new ServiceLocal.Service1Client();
        await client.SubmitDropOffAsync(id);
        await client.CloseAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just a note: this works as long as you mark the calling method with an "async" modifier.